# I can't inset building's face correctly

Tags: modeling

I am trying to make a skyscraper building.
I made a floor for it.
When I try to build above, I used inset tool but it didn't what I expected.

this is what I expect (only outer edges inset)

[image: this is what I expect (only outer edges inset)]

this is what I got

[image]

Blender exchange file

[image]

---

I tried your solution but It still inset adjoint edges

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like where the inset splits, there are duplicate unconnected vertices. You can guess it also because the edges looks a bit thicker/darker there. Maybe there are even faces inbetween?

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Brinkmann is right. You likely have duplicated vertices in the roof of your mesh. Enter Edit Mode on your mesh, make sure vertex select (1 key) is active, go into size view (Numpad 3 key) and activate wireframe mode (Z key). Now box select the whole top of your mesh, including the tops of the walls. Now select Mesh > Merge > Merge by Distance. This will remove any duplicate vertices and allow you to use the inset tool properly.

Comment: Hello Gordon and Copperplate, I tried your suggestions but it didn't work I guess or I did something wrong

Comment: I tried your suggestion and screen shot

Comment: Can you edit your original question and add the embed code to the file on Blend Exchange? Thanks

Comment: Okay, I added code to my question

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at it now.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking forward

Comment: 1080p video is now available on YouTube, but you'll still need to turn the volume way up, sorry about that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

So in this case, the issue is not duplicated vertices, but rather **disconnected faces.** If you don't mind watching me ramble and make mistakes for nearly 38 minutes, I made a video for you showing how even fixing the issue of disconnected faces **does not completely solve** the issue with the inset tool you were having, because the corner faces will **very quickly overlap each other and cause problems**.

**Basically you need to approach the modelling differently**, as demonstrated in the video. There are many ways to do this. I showed a few ways in the video, but the best way (near the end of the video) in my opinion is just to extrude the perimeter walls up, extrude in, fix any edges that went the wrong way, then extrude up again. At the very least you might learn a few new things about Blender from watching me goof up in the video. PS. Sorry the audio is quite low, you'll probably have to turn the volume up. :-)

Also, YouTube is still processing the higher res videos, so you will have to check back in a little while to watch the full quality version (1440p): https://youtu.be/cci59mn9dcw